# Can I sue my gym for over charging me?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, new-york-state, civil-law

They have refused to correct the mistake.  I have asked them about 3 times and finally given up and just cancelled my membership.

Comment: An often overlooked mechanism is the Better Business Bureau...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I sue...?](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/questions/224/answering-can-i-be-sued-questions)

Comment: @Pat - What does the BBB do ?

Comment: @feetwet - more specifically can I sue for the time I spend putting together my case ?

Comment: My guess is even if I win the $200 or so , it won't be worth if I spend 10 hours going through the process, unless I'm compensated for that time.

Comment: If that's your question you should update it accordingly.  The answer is generally "no," but at least that would make this a new and interesting question.

Comment: In addition to @PatW.'s suggestion, there is another often overlooked mechanism in New York City: the [Department of Consumer Affairs](http://www1.nyc.gov/site/dca/index.page).

Comment: The BBB does lots of things, but two relevant ones are 1) it has a trust rating system, and 2) has a well-developed complaint process. BBB members treat the complaints seriously because failing to resolve them can lead to a downgrade in rating. You may try searching to see if your gym is rated by the BBB

Comment: Did you pay with a credit card? Call your bank and initiate a chargeback.

Comment: Negative reviews and ratings on the popular ratings sites will probably be worth more than $200. It won't get you your money back, but at least you can enjoy knowing (a) they will lose out in the long run and (b) others won't  have the same problem. Seriously, it would take a very small number of new members quitting to cost them the $200 they owe you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to sue, and can prove they overcharged -  consider going to the small claims court.  It should cost you $15 + time - unless you loose quite badly - in which case its conceivable the court could award costs against you (I don't know if this is true of the small claims court in NY).

You can represent yourself, so no heavy legal bills.

It will take a a few hours of your time to prepare and have the hearing.

Of-course, very often, just by filing you will get the opposing party to sort out the issue - and probably won't even need to go to court.

Answer (score 1):

Can you sue? Yes. Will you win? If they are in violation of your contract, probably, if they *might* be in violation? still probably but there is a huge risk that you will have to pay court costs and lawyer costs. Is it worth your time, no.

Comment: But we don't know if lawsuit is pre-empted by an arbitration clause. So I'd say at most "maybe".

Comment: I would have to say maybe as well. I know this is NY but I've done exactly that in Texas. I filed in small claims and it cost me 30 dollars. I paid about 4 dollars for the jury fee, and the judge allowed me to 'serve' them via certified mail so that cost me 6 or 7 dollars.  That was definitely worth my time. They settled so fast, made it right, and gave me several free months.